# Android: Getting data from server to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

My app polls data from server after it was notified by cloud messaging.

The data is fetched in GcmListenerService. My current approach is to use an Intent to transfer the data to the relevant activity via a broadcast receiver. This only works if the activity is in foreground.

How to store the data fetched by GcmListenerService such that the activity will update itself according to the fetched data as soon as it is resumed?

Comment: you can store the data in shared preferences or sqlite database so that when resumed you can fetch required data from server.

Comment: do it via content provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use service binding.

Declare a Binder implementation as part of your service definition:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
    // Set this field whenever you receive data from the cloud.
    private ArrayList<MyDataType> latestCloudData;

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public ArrayList<MyDataType> getLatestCloudData() {
            return MyService.this.latestCloudData;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

Bind and unbind to your service in your activity's `onStart` and `onStop`, respectively, by providing an implementation of ServiceConnection:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // Provides an interface for communicating with the service.
    MyBinder mMyBinder = null;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder binder) {
            // Successfully bound, cast the IBinder to a MyBinder.
            MyBinder myBinder = (MyBinder) binder;
            // Can now use the MyBinder instance to communicate with the service.
            MyActivity.this.mMyBinder = myBinder;
            mBound = true;
            // Use the MyBinder to get the latest cloud data from the service and update your view.
            ArrayList<MyDataType> cloudData = MyActivity.this.mMyBinder.getLatestCloudData();
            MyActivity.this.updateViewWithCloudData(cloudData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };

    private void updateViewWithCloudData(ArrayList<MyDataType> data) {
        // Use the data to update your view here...
    }
}
```

See [the Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for more information about Bound Services (the example above is a modified version of the example found there).

Also note that this will only help you when your activity moves from the background to the foreground (or is recreated). If you *also* want to receive updates while the activity is in the foreground, you should also perform a broadcast which your activity should listen for. However, you do not need to bundle the cloud data as part of this broadcast. The broadcast can simply be a simple notification prompting the activity to query the service for the new data using `MyBinder.getLatestCloudData()`.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great approach. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to upvote yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, GcmListenerService does not allow to override onBind. Any idea what else I could do?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that limitation. A slightly hacky approach could be to create a 2nd service that offers binding (as it does not inherit from GcmListenerService). This service could register a broadcast receiver as per your current solution for when the activity is in the foreground. When it receives the broadcast from your GcmListenerService, this second service could cache the result and expose it to the activity through service binding.